# NameError: ("name 'true' is not defined", 'occurred at index 0')

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\dd\Desktop\test.csv')
df
```

Out

```
userid  url
0   123 x.com
1   345 y.com
```

Code

```
def create_dict(row):
    return ({"userid" : row.userid ,"data": {"url": row.url},"bool":true})
```

I dont want to give `true` to `'true'` because i am hitting the api. I need to return as `true` only

Apply

`df['out'] = df.apply(lambda row: create_dict(row), axis=1)`

Expected out

```
userid  url results
0   123 x.com   {'userid': 123, 'data': {'url': 'x.com'}, 'bool': true}
1   345 y.com   {'userid': 345, 'data': {'url': 'y.com'}, 'bool': true}
```

Deisclaimer : please dont make this as duplicate as

by doing `return ({"userid" : row.userid ,"data": {"url": row.url},"bool":"true"})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If use `true` it means variable `true`, if use `True` it is boolean value `true` in python.

So correct way is:

```
def create_dict(row):
    return ({"userid" : row.userid ,"data": {"url": row.url},"bool":True})
```